# How to Authenticate ServiceNow(SNOW)User using SOAP API in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap

I am Developing application console for listing all incidents avail in SNOW.
I have implemented that by adding service reference in IDE and called function based on service references... but quite little bit confused how to authenticate SNOW user using service reference...

My App.config file

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <configuration>
       <startup>
         <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
       </startup>
   <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="ServiceNowSoap" allowCookies="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000" maxBufferSize="20000000" maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxArrayLength="20000000" maxStringContentLength="20000000" />
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="">
          <extendedProtectionPolicy policyEnforcement="Never"/>
         </transport>
          <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
      <binding name="ServiceNowSoap1" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
  <client>
       <endpoint address="https://****.service-now.com/incident.do?SOAP"
         binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="ServiceNowSoap"
       contract="ServiceReference1.ServiceNowSoap" name="ServiceNowSoap" />
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

My mainwindow.xaml

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        ServiceReference1.ServiceNowSoapClient soapClient = new ServiceReference1.ServiceNowSoapClient();
        soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "****";
        soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "*****";

        ServiceReference1.getRecords Records = new ServiceReference1.getRecords();
        ServiceReference1.getRecordsResponseGetRecordsResult[] Results = soapClient.getRecords(Records);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        data.TableName = "ServiceNow Incidents";
        data.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{new DataColumn("Number"),  
                                                 new DataColumn("Opened"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Short Description"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Caller"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Priority"),
                                                 new DataColumn("State"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Category"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Assigned Group"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Assigned To"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Updated On"),
                                                 new DataColumn("Updated By")});

        for (int i = 0; i < Results.Length; i++)
        {
            DataRow row = data.NewRow();
            row["Number"] = Results[i].number;
            row["Opened"] = Results[i].opened_at;
            row["Short Description"] = Results[i].short_description;
            row["Caller"] = Results[i].caller_id;
            row["Priority"] = Results[i].priority;
            row["State"] = Results[i].state;
            row["Category"] = Results[i].category;
            row["Assigned Group"] = Results[i].assignment_group;
            row["Assigned To"] = Results[i].assigned_to;
            row["Updated On"] = Results[i].sys_updated_on;
            row["Updated By"] = Results[i].sys_updated_by;
            data.Rows.Add(row);
        } 

        gridview.DataContext = data.DefaultView;
        gridview.Items.Refresh();
    }
```

Comment: is SNOW a service?  Can you provide a link to their website?

Comment: yes...it's a webservice(servicenow) www.developers.service-now.com

Comment: You may need to contact their support as nowhere in their documentation does it say how to authenticate against their service.

Comment: On a side note, unless you have a strong reason to use WCF, I would recommend using their REST API.